# ROW_NUMBER() in BQ always changes every time I rerun the query

Tags: google-bigquery, row-number

I am using BQ and am using ROW_NUMBER to give my data an identifier. However, I found this issue where every time I rerun the query, the ROW_NUMBER would give me different outcome.

In my database, I have 12 fields in total and I use this query

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12) row_number
```

I have run this query for multiple times, but the outcome would always be different each time I run it.

For example:

> - 1st Run: Merchant A has Row 1212
> - 2nd Run: The exact same Merchant A has Row 2938

Is there anything wrong that I do here? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Turns out we shouldn't use number for ORDER BY in ROW_NUMBER() function.

Instead of using number, I use the field name instead and it works the magic. The ROW_NUMBER() keeps giving me the same answer.

Instead of this:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12) row_number
```

Use this:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY field_name_1, field_name_2) row_number
```